# Jquery: How to get the content from object HTMLDivElement?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, sorting, drag-and-drop

I have a task bar. in that i am listing all the tasks and also i provided drag on drop option. While drag and drop i need to perform some action. For that i have written my code like as follows..

```
  $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    revert: true,
    connectWith  : ".sortable",
    stop : function(){ alert(this)}
  });
```

I have tried with
     this.val(), this.innerHtml . but its not working.

for alert (this) it's returning [object HTMLDivElement]. I want to see the content inside this HTMLDivElement. How to do that please guide.

Comment: @Exception it's showing blank.

Comment: see if there is any console errors??

Comment: this.html is not a function

Comment: @Exception $(this).html()  is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60493/discussion-between-pooja-agarwal-and-exception).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$(this).html();
```

instead of

```
this.html()
```